# How can I write a custom error class that will require a property if a certain argument exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I'm creating a custom error class like this:

```js
import { OperationalError } from './baseErrors';

type ErrorProps = {
  message: string;
  paymentProvider: 'stripe' | 'braintree';
  failedChargeData: {
    errorMessage: string;
    stripePaymentIntentId?: string;
    braintreeChargeId?: string;
    eventType: string;
  };
};

export class FailedPaymentError extends OperationalError {
  constructor({ message, paymentProvider, failedChargeData }: ErrorProps) {
    const properties = { failedChargeData, paymentProvider };
    super(message, properties, 400);
  }
}
```

I want to improve this though.

I want to write a conditional type of some sort so that if `paymentProvider === 'stripe'`, then `ErrorProps` will require a `stripePaymentIntentId`. Whereas if `paymentProvider === 'braintree'`, then a `braintreeChargeId` is required.

I think I need to do something like this?

```js
import { OperationalError } from './baseErrors';

type PaymentProvider = 'stripe' | 'braintree';
type ErrorProps<T> = {
  message: string;
  paymentProvider: T;
  failedChargeData: T extends 'stripe'
    ? {
        errorMessage: string;
        stripePaymentIntentId: string;
        eventType: string;
      }
    : {
        errorMessage: string;
        braintreeChargeId: string;
        eventType: string;
      };
};

export class FailedPaymentError extends OperationalError {
  constructor({
    message,
    paymentProvider,
    failedChargeData,
  }: ErrorProps<PaymentProvider>) {
    const properties = { failedChargeData, paymentProvider };
    super(message, properties, 400);
  }
}
```

So I can then throw the error like this:

```js
const failedChargeData = {
  errorMessage: message,
  stripePaymentIntentId: e.type && e.requestId,
  eventType: e.type || 'unexpectedFailedPayment',
};

throw new FailedPaymentError({
  message,
  paymentProvider: 'stripe',
  failedChargeData,
});
```

But this doesn't quite work. TS doesn't complain if I pass through the wrong payment provider. It's also not particularly DRY.

This DOES work but several lines seem needlessly duplicated:

```js
type ErrorProps =
  | {
      message: string;
      paymentProvider: 'stripe';
      failedChargeData: {
        errorMessage: string;
        stripePaymentIntentId: string;
        eventType: string;
      };
    }
  | {
      message: string;
      paymentProvider: 'braintree';
      failedChargeData: {
        errorMessage: string;
        braintreeChargeId: string;
        eventType: string;
      };
    };
```

How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminated union in your last example is exactly correct.

You can dry it up by extracting the discriminated typings from the base interface.

```
type MapErrorProps<T, K> = {
  message: string;
  paymentProvider: T;
  failedChargeData: {
    errorMessage: string;
    eventType: string;
  } & K;
};

// Map each type to a required data interface
type ErrorProps = MapErrorProps<"stripe", { stripePaymentIntentId: string }>
  | MapErrorProps<"braintree", { braintreeChargeId: string }>;
  | MapErrorProps<"iceCream", { flavor: string }>;
```